# Multi language text area

Tags: usability, text, language, anti-patterns, multilingual

I have a scenario in my application, where users have an option to view and edit a multi-language description of a given wine.

For now, the solution is to have separate text areas for each language. For a view, however, I am using a toggle button for each language and displaying the corresponding description

Is there a common/better way to have display and input of multilingual text description?

Comment: What reason do users have to view the descriptions in multiple languages? Do they need to translate? Do they need to find errors? I wonder: If you display all textareas in the edit mode, why not also display all textareas in the view mode?

Comment: The system is thought to manage the content of huge wine catalog. Managers should be able to provide multi-language text and view/edit them for further use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is provided by Google Translate: there is just one textarea. Users can set language with some buttons or the system suggest them the language detected.

If you want limit the range of languages the feedback could be: **"language not supported"**

Technically you can do it with the [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/detecting-language)

---

### [image]

Comment: Great point! I was surfing around to find similar solutions. Paradoxically enough, google translate never came to my mind.