# Multi Language Description

Tags: language

I have a small problem with creating multi-language description. In the picture below, I showed my current state of what I made (I took the idea from [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/117287/multi-language-text-area)). But anyway I need a way for every language to have a translation, so do you have some solution that it's done in practice?

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. Are you saying that you need your design to allow the user to enter many more languages than just English and Spanish?

Comment: sure, look for any WordPress multilanguage translator, it's basically your image (with pre-selected languages, so it can have 2, 3 or 100)

Comment: @Izquierdo Yes I am saying that.

Comment: @Paco Will your users always need access to *all* languages? Usually there is a back-end setting where an admin selects which languages to support, and then the content creator would work in an editor like the one you linked to, showing the supported languages. If they truly need to access every language available, can you explain more about the use case? Thanks.

Comment: @Izquierdo Request is to support all languages since it's a SaaS that sells all around the world so yea.

Answer (score 1):

Your product should be able to support all languages, but your end user (the person entering descriptions) will most likely only be working in a few languages chosen by his or her business.

I recommend a two-part approach:

1. In your product settings, let each business select the languages that they'll be using. Like Devin said in the comments, Wordpress has some good patterns for this. Here is an example of a screen that allows an admin to set the languages they'll need.

[image: Wordpress language setup]

2. Then, when the content creator is adding content, they can switch languages using tabs, as shown in the wireframe below. You could use visual indicators such as what I've done with "French" to let the user know that the content section is still empty.

[image: Language switcher]

If the end user truly needs to switch between all languages, you could provide a dropdown list instead of the tabs. But, I would guess that most businesses are using a subset based on their available translation resources, and you should design for them. Pareto principle, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback I'll try something like this, that plugin is paid only on WP ?

Comment: There are likely several plugins that could accomplish this, perhaps you could check out the Wordpress marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so why not use a two column setup like so:

[image: multi-language description]

You could also try complicating your developer's lives by doing something like this:

[image: better communicates which language you are editing]

Or better yet, also add an indicator to let the editor know which options they have already filled in. Maybe a rounded checkbox:

[image: multi-language description box with indicator for filled in options]

Comment: Thanks I'll try something like this and fill in with more info, currently thaht description would be in modal so I don't know about that scroll.